# Will client sites on clientsite.mydomain.com affect SEO at www.mydomain.com?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, subdomain, cname

Example:
Petterson Rekvisitta is a company I am building a website for. He has a domain: `petterson.com`, and will eventually move there.

During development I set up his site on `petterson.mydomain.com` before I eventually set up a CNAME from `www.petterson.com` to `petterson.mydomain.com` + a 301 redirect from `petterson.mydomain.com` to `www.petterson.com`.

1. Will googling for "mydomain.com" also give results for "petterson.mycompanydomain.com"? (making my client an unnecessary competitor)
2. Will **content** on `petterson.mydomain.com` affect SEO for `www.mydomain.com`? (like if petterson is hacked and suddenly is a porn-site, will it hurt me?)
3. Will any of the above change after I do the CNAME and 301 redirect to `petterson.com`?

Comment: Do you mean "mydomain" instead of "mycompanydomain" in your first question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will googling for "mydomain.com" also give results for
>   "petterson.mycompanydomain.com"? (making my client an unnecessary
>   competitor)

Not after you set up a `301 redirect`. If it's indexed right now, Google will eventually delete it.

> Will content on petterson.mydomain.com affect SEO for
>   www.mydomain.com? (like if petterson is hacked and suddenly is a
>   porn-site, will it hurt me?)

It's a subdomain of your domain and it can affect SEO in some ways. However, once you set up the `301 redirect` there will be no problem. Next time, you should prevent the 'development site' to be indexed by searches using [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html) o [noindex tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=es).

> Will any of the above change after I do the cname and 301 redirect to
>   petterson.com?

Once you do that, everything will be fine